# How do I parse a JSON tree and check if the names are unique throughout the tree structure?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6, tree

I have this tree which can go much deeper than that and I need to make sure that the names of every unit, entity and portfolio are unique throughout the tree. Could anyone please help me with a JS (ES6) implementation of parsing this tree and checking the uniqueness of the names? Thank you very much!

```
reduxTree: {
    units: [
      {
        name: 'ROOT',
        units: [
          {
            name: 'ORG1',
            units: [],
            entities: [
              {
                name: 'LE1',
                portfolios: [
                  {
                    name: 'PO1', 
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
          },
          {
            name: 'ORG2',
            units: [],
            entities: [
              {
                name: 'LE2',
                portfolios: [
                  {
                    name: 'PO2',
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
          }
        ],
        entities: [
          {
            name: 'LE3',
            portfolios: [
              {
                name: 'PO3',
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: might wanna try recursion

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive approach where I check all the names and if one appears twice, I just break the iteration

```js
const reduxTree = { units: [{ name: 'ROOT', units: [{ name: 'ORG1', units: [], entities: [{ name: 'LE1', portfolios: [{ name: 'PO1', }] }], }, { name: 'ORG2', units: [], entities: [{ name: 'LE2', portfolios: [{ name: 'PO2', }] }], } ], entities: [{ name: 'LE3', portfolios: [{ name: 'PO3', }] }], }] }; 
  
const mySet = new Set();
function validateTree(obj){
   if(!obj || obj.length == 0){
   return true;
   }
   if(mySet.has(obj[0].name)){
      return false;   
   } else {
     return validateTree(obj[0].units) && validateTree(obj[0].entities) && validateTree(obj[0].portfolios)
   }
}

console.log(validateTree(reduxTree.units))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a closure over a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) which collects seen names and tyke a destructuring for objects to separate `name` and the rest of the object.

After a check for the name, if in the set, it returns with false, otherwise add the name to the set and iterate and check the rest properties.

```js
const
    hasUniqueNames = (object, names = new Set) => {
        const c = ({name, ...rest }) => {
            if (name !== undefined) if (names.has(name)) return false;
            names.add(name);
            return Object.values(rest).every(v => !v || typeof v !== 'object' || c(v));
        };

        return c(object);
    },
    reduxTree = { units: [{ name: 'ROOT', units: [{ name: 'ORG1', units: [], entities: [{ name: 'LE1', portfolios: [{ name: 'PO1' }] }] }, { name: 'ORG2', units: [], entities: [{ name: 'LE2', portfolios: [{ name: 'PO2' }] }] }], entities: [{ name: 'LE3', portfolios: [{ name: 'PO3' }] }] }] },
    result = hasUniqueNames(reduxTree);

console.log(hasUniqueNames(reduxTree));
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a go with this

I extract all `"name":"<name>"` and use a Set to see if they are unique

```js
const reduxTree = { units: [{ name: 'ROOT', units: [{ name: 'ORG1', units: [], entities: [{ name: 'LE1', portfolios: [{ name: 'PO1', }] }], }, { name: 'ORG2', units: [], entities: [{ name: 'LE2', portfolios: [{ name: 'PO2', }] }], } ], entities: [{ name: 'LE3', portfolios: [{ name: 'PO3', }] }], }] } 

const names = [...JSON.stringify(reduxTree).matchAll(/"name":"(\w+)"/g)].map(m => m[1])
const unique = new Set(names).size === names.length

console.log("Unique?",unique,names.join(","))
```

Comment: Why downvote. It works. It works for large objects too